# BuildConfig class generation in Android project

Tags: android, build.gradle

Good day,
I have an Andoid project with following build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply true
}

android {
    namespace 'com.vpavlov.moneymanager'
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId =  "com.vpavlov.moneymanager"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_14
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_14
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"

    //Charts
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'

    implementation "androidx.concurrent:concurrent-futures:1.1.0"
}
```

And I tried to get app vesrion name via BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME but my BuildConifg class was not generated. I have BuildConfig class from `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3` dependency instead

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URWA0.png)

How can I generate my own BuildConfig class with custom parameters.

P.S.
I cleaned and rebuilt my project, invalidated cache. Nothing helped.

**Thank you**

I tried to sync build.gradle, invalidate caches and project rebuild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to your build.gradle file and then clean or rebuild the project, OR invalidate the cache. It worked in my case.

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig true
    }
}
```